# Razor Safe Navigation Operator?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

Is there a way to navigate the Object Graph in a Razor View in a null-safe manner (without having `@if` guard-blocks?

For example, I have the following in `Index.cshtml`:

```
@foreach (Store.Models.Product product in @Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td>@product.Id</td>  
        <td>@product.ProductName</td>  
        <td>@String.Format("{0:C}", @product.Price)</td>
        <td>@product.Quantity</td>
        @if (@product.Category != null)
        {
            <td>@product.Category.CategoryName</td>
        }
        else 
        {
            <td></td>
        }
    </tr>
}
```

Not all of my Products have Categories.  When they do not, `Product.Category` is null.

What I would really like to do is safely be able to navigate the object graph and not have to worry about `NullReferenceException` blowing up the view.

In Groovy/Grails, I am used to using the [Safe Navigation Operator](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Operators#Operators-SafeNavigationOperator) and would do something like:

```
<td>@product?.Category?.CategoryName</td>
```

Of course, that did not work in Razor.

Is there any sort of equivalent in Razor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to use an inline conditional:

```
<td>@(product.Category != null ? product.Category : "")</td>
```

Just makes the code more compact

Comment: That worked, and it turned 8 lines of code into 1 line.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I'm using this one, just surround the code with parentheses @( ):

```
<a class="float-right bg-warning text-dark">
    @(order.BilledAmount?.ToString("0,0.00"))
</a>
```

Comment: Didn't work for me, I get an exception saying "The ? character cannot be used here." (I'm using VB.NET but don't think it should make a difference on this)

Comment: @EduardoWada I think your object might not be a nullable type, this works for nullables like the type "Int32?"